# Cómo puedo crear controles con posición sumada?

Tags: c#

Necesito crear un conjunto de controles, justo como en este [enlace](https://youtu.be/8JkbQY93xYY), solo que, en vez de mostrarse de arriba a abajo, necesito que sumen la posición `X` del control anterior. Algo así como:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.X = 200;
```

Para que sumara en 200, así `b2` tendría de posición `X = 400`, `b3` tendría la posición `X = 600` y así.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo acabo de terminar.

Comment: Puedes responder tu propia pregunta y así mostrarle a la comunidad como lo haz resuelto. Para esto te invito a ver el siguiente artículo: [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente para resolver tu problema

```
//Defino la distancia vertical que habrá entre cada Control dinámico que vaya creando
var distance = 50;
//Cantidad de elementos a crear
var cantidad = 3;
//Hago un ciclo para crear los controles
for(int i=0;i < cantidad; i++){
    //Creo un botón
    Button btn = new Button();
    //Le establezco el Texto que va a tener
    btn.Text = String.Format("New Button {0}",i+1);
    //Establezco la posición horizontal
    btn.Left = 50;
    //Si es el primero se en el eje de las Y donde ubicarlo
    if(i == 0){
        btn.Top = 150;
    } else {
       //Sino busco el último control añadido al formulario
       var last = Controls.Last();
       //Establezco su posición vertical basado en la distancia, 
       //el largo y la posición del eje Y que tenia este ultimo
       btn.Top = last.Top+distance+last.Height;
    }
    //Añado el control al formulario
    Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: En la parte del código : var Last = Controls.Last(); Hay un error, supongo que “Last” es una propiedad, pero no aparece en sus propiedades (ni métodos, en caso de que fuera un metodo).

Comment: Prueba con Controls.Cast<Control>().Last()

Comment: Esta bien, pero no me deja hacer una variable, el error es : Cannot asign method group to an implicity-typed variable

Comment: var last = Controls[Controls.Count-1]; Que sucede si haces esto!!!!!!!!